# Find kind of product in input lines

Tags: ruby, regex, match

Here is the following problem I am trying to approach. I am going to say how I am doing it and I am looking for an approach that would be **less complex** (and cleaner :P).

Given inputs like this:

First input

```
1 soccer ball costs 30 
1 piano costs 500
1 guitars costs 200
```

Second input

```
1 luxury bottle of whiskey costs 10.20
1 package of luxury caviar costs 53
```

I want to calculate the final price for each line and the final price for each input.  In order to calculate the final price for each line, I take into account that:

- If the item processed is related to sports, I want to add 2 (so first line would be 32). If it's a music item, I want to add 4 (so second line would be 504).
- If the item processed is food related, I want to add 5 (so both lines of second input would have an increment of 5).
- If the item processed is luxury kind, I want to add 10.

I am having troubles in one thing:

- Identify and mapping which kind of item is in a particular line.

Using regex I am able to find the part of the line that is supposed to be the item:

```
soccer ball
piano
guitars
bottle of whisky
package of caviar
```

I know it might be a really generalist question, but I am wondering what would be a good way to find which kind of good each item is.

Right now I have a structure like this:

```
{"soccer" => "sports", "piano" => "music", "guitars" => "music", "whisky" => "food", "caviar" => "food"}
```

And then I try to match any of the keys of my hash with the item in a particular line. Can you think of a better way, API or anything that would make this less complex?

Comment: You already have this question, why not edit the other one?

Comment: There are completely different questions.  On the other question I was asking how to get the different parts. Here I want to know how to analyze one particular part SEMANTICALLY.

Answer (score 0):

You have an inverted hierarchy. Each key in your array should be a category, and the value should be an array of all the items that fall into that category.

```
{"sports"=> ["soccer"], "music" => ["guitars", "piano"], "food" => ["caviar","whisky"]}
```

Comment: If I use this structure, how would I do the matching? I need to go key by key in the structure to see if it matches with the item.

Comment: Yes you would need, but there's maybe some search functions already done.

Comment: Performing such a search is not difficult, and this structure is superior as long as you do not have multiple categories for each item, in which case it is equivalent.